# Cannot Import My NPM Package With ES6 Import/Export Syntax

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, module, importerror

I am creating an NPM package called `notifman`. Here's what I did:

1. Created the `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "notifman",
  "version": "1.0.5",
  "description": "Advanced, Lightweight and Powerful Notification Library For Plain JS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "npx nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "notification",
    "frontend",
    "js",
    "plain"
  ],
  "author": "...",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "notifman": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

2. I wrote the `index.js`:

```js
console.log("hello world");
```

3. Wrote a README.md
4. Tested the package in Node.js and it worked fine.
5. Originally, I wanted the package to work in the browser, so I tried changing the code in `index.js` to:

```js
export default function getRoot() {
  return document.getElementById("root");
}
```

6. Then, I wanted to test using import/export syntax, I suppose it is:

```js
import getRoot from "notifman";
getRoot.textContent = "hello world";
```

The error message is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "notifman". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

**Partially Solved**:
I just used Webpack, and it worked fine. But I am sure Webpack is not required. I want it to work WITHOUT webpack. This is why this is partially solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
"type": "module"
```

**add this to your package.json just below main **

Comment: I've tried it. I've also used `<script type="module" ... src="..."></script>`

Comment: I think I have to use Webpack for this, I did and it worked btw